# tooltip doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

```
<?php 
foreach ($query as $row){
echo  '<tr><td>
    <label class="checkbox">
    '.form_checkbox('delete[]', $row['link']).anchor("site/see_art/".$row['feed_id'],$row['title'],'class="abc"').
    '<div class="tooltip-inner">'.$row['description'].'</div></td><td>'.substr($row['pub_date'], 5, 12).
    '</label>
    </td></tr>'
    ;
}
?>
```

JS:

```
$(".abc").mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout($('.tooltip-inner').data('timeoutId'));
    $('.tooltip-inner').show(200);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.tooltip-inner').hide(200);
    }, 650);
    $('.tooltip-inner').data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
});

$(".tooltip-inner").mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout($('.tooltip-inner').data('timeoutId'));
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.tooltip-inner').hide(200);
    }, 650);
    $('.tooltip-inner').data('timeoutId', timeoutId); 
});
```

In view I have a table where I displayed some titles. I want to display the description of title when I hover the link. My problem is when I hover on a link it displayed me the description for all the links. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:codeigniter]?  Seems like a jQuery/JavaScript issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `$('.tooltip-inner')` selector - it selects ALL elements with `tooltip-inner` class.

The `div` you're trying to select (`<div class="tooltip-inner">`) is a sibling of the anchor triggering the event (`<a class="abc"`). To select this `div`, use [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method:

```
$(this).siblings(".tooltip-inner")...
```

However you will need to rework the other parts of your HTML and JavaScript to have it working.

Comment: the problem is that i must do this with JS.

Comment: @user3429546 oh I missed that totally. My answer is not valid at all then. Do you mean that your tooltip works (shows and hides when it should) but it displays wrong content?

Comment: the tooltip it works but when i hover any title it appears the tooltip for every title not only for the title that i hover